# C# Issue with subclassed property name in a user control DataBind()

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, user-controls

I'm creating my own user control in a asp.net project and have two asp list elements in this control that I want to set a data source from another class' list objects.

My exception error is:

```
DataBinding: 'TeamTracker.Flash.ErrorMessage' does not contain a property with the name 'message'.
```

The user control looks like this:

```
public partial class flashMessage : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_PreRender (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TTPage page = (TTPage)this.Page;
        WebFlash flash = page.flashMessages;
        messages.DataSource = flash.NoticeMessages;
        messages.DataTextField = "message";
        messages.DataValueField = "name";
        messages.DataBind();
        errorMessages.DataSource = flash.ErrorMessages;
        errorMessages.DataTextField = "message";
        errorMessages.DataValueField = "name";
        errorMessages.DataBind();
    }
}
```

ErrorMessage is the class bellow:

```
namespace TeamTracker.Flash
{
    public class ErrorMessage : Message
    {
        public ErrorMessage(string message)
        {
            this.message = message;
        }
    }
}
```

The message property is defined in the parent abstract class

```
 namespace TeamTracker.Flash
 {
     public abstract class Message
     {
         public string name, message, colour;
     }
 }
```

Is there a reason why the data Bind cant see this property "message"? The error occurred on the errorMessages bind as it had two objects in the list as NoticeMessages had 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the binding expects a property.  `name`, `message` and `colour` are fields.
What it looks like you need is something like this:

```
public string name
{
    get;
    set;
}
public string  message
{
    get;
    set;
}
public string colour
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Comment: Cheers, I got confused with the definition of properties and fields, i'll have to read up on this. Thanks!

Comment: No worries. Something worth noting, though, is that the convention in c# is for properties to CamelCase with an upper case first letter, while fields have a lower case first letter

Answer (score 2):

You need to use public properties for databinding,

```
public abstract class Message
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Colour { get; set; }
}
```

if you can't change the fields to properties, then do as below.

```
errorMessages.DataSource = flash.ErrorMessages.Select(x=> 
                             new { Message = x.message, Name = x.name}).ToList();
errorMessages.DataTextField = "Message";
errorMessages.DataValueField = "Name";
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution and explination, has aided my understanding